# What does a `~` tilde in a CSS `url()` do?

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

E.g. `@import url("~./foobar");`

Saw it [here](https://github.com/izaakschroeder/font-loader/blob/0e6a9c5c4098279cfd7274d018de2609b608e04a/example/test.css#L2), not sure if it's some package specific thing or if it's actual CSS syntax.

Comment: @JackMiller No, this is not a selection operator, it’s part of a file directory.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The [CSS `@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) path `<url>` is usually relative to the current working directory.

So using the prefix `~` at the start of the path tells Webpack's css-loader to resolve the import "like a module", starting from the `node_modules` directory.

What that means is that if you have a node module called `normalize` installed, and you need to import a css file from within it named `/normalize.css`, you can do that with:

```
@import "~normalize/normalize.css";
```

---

In your linked example, inside `font-loader/example/test.js` there is an import of a module called `font-boon`.

```
var boon = require('./font-boon');
```

Inside of `font-loader/example/test.css` the font-boon module is @imported so that it is available in `text.css`.

`@import url("~./font-boon");`

Comment: so.. basically, is `~` contain `node_module` path?

Comment: `~` is apparently [handled by webpack `css-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#import), the [raw postcss-import doesn't support it](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader/issues/166#issuecomment-275169151).

Answer (score 38):

**UPDATE March 2021**

From [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules) tilde '~' imports are deprecated and is recommended to be removed.

Comment: Note that the `~` imports are deprecated in `sass-loader`, but not in `css-loader`. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url

Answer (score 7):

Using an @import statement assumes you're importing from the **node_modules** folder. So for example if you're trying to import bootstrap.css, you'd use

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
```

That is, you're putting the path relative to the node_modules folder.