# Angular material Could not find Angular Material core theme

Tags: angular, themes

In my Angular2 project I install lastest material plugin from https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started. Next I add `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` to my css file for my component. But in my console Angular shows this error:

> material.es5.js:148 Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming`

The material components not working.
Whats wrong?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this file is a SASS file (.scss), maybe you can try with that?

Comment: I don't have any sass file

Comment: No, you don't have sass files, but the angular material module does. That's how you use your own theme (again, if I recall correctly), so try seeing in the node module if it's a SASS or css file.

Comment: If you're working on a custom theming project, and you added a file to your "angular.json" file, make sure you stop the **ng serve** and restart it for the new "theme.scss" to load.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Please insert below code into your **styles.css** which is located in your **src** folder.

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

You can select any css under the **prebuilt-themes** folder.

Comment: Just as @jelbourn mentioned at Issues [4739](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4739):  Load prebuilt-themes in **Global**  (styles.css), rather than in Component's **styleUrls**.

Comment: Use ~ for easier path to node modules. Example: @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

Comment: As @BraveNinja said, tilde "~" allows you to avoid issues with paths. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39535907/877464 for a better explanation why.

Comment: why is this not handled by angular add @angular/material itself?

Comment: @Trevor the link has become broken, that paragraph is not there anymore

Comment: Updated link to docs: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Answer (score 37):

put that code into your angular-cli.json file

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
  ],
```

it's works fine for me

Comment: This is the real correct answer. Never use style.css for import other css. ALWAYS use angular.json file.

Comment: @Bluex why is this better?

Comment: @Rocco because it’s like style css in-line.. it works but is not a good solution rather is the worst

Comment: This is the best answer. If you get this error with later versions 9+ after running ```ng add @angular/material```  just terminate the batch job and re-run the app, sometimes the configs aren't fully loaded when compiling.

Comment: The latest docs demand this approach ... https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Answer (score 19):

I got it working with the following steps:

1) Import this (or other) Material theme into your main css file:

```
@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

2) Also make sure to register this main css file with the **app.component** file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css'
  ]
})
```

3) Double check that the components you need are imported from *@angular/material* in your **app.module** file

```
import { MdCardModule, MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: not working because  node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss is overriding

Answer (score 10):

Add the following line to your `src/styles.css`

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

You can try other Css classes as well. Here are the available classes:

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css';`

`@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';`

Comment: not working because  node_modules\@angular\material\_theming.scss is overriding

Answer (score 6):

Add:

`@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`

to your `style.css`

Answer (score 6):

If you need only the material icons and you don't want import the whole material css use this, in your root css:

```
/** disable angular mat theme warning */
.mat-theme-loaded-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If this is happening during testing with Karma, add the following `pattern` to the `files` list in your `karma.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
   config.set({
    basePath: '',
    ...,
    files: [
        {pattern: './node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css', included: true, watched: true}
    ],
    ...
}
```

For more detail see here: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/44073085-a-testing-with-material-components-guide-to-demonstrate-including-core-theme-in-test-suite

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'
```

to the **style.css** file,
OR add

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the head section of **index.html** file

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Angular-CLI, you'll need to make a reference to the themes file, e.g. "candy.scss" in the .angular-cli.json file.  Look closely, do you have a *.scss?  It's a Sass file.  Look here for information: [Angular Material 2 Theming instructions](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).  So, in the .angular-cli.json, under the styles property, add "themes/candy.scss", next to the "themes/styles.css".  I have a folder in my projects called "themes".  I put the styles.css and the candy.scss in the themes folder.  Now, Angular-CLI can find your theme.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @import statements as mentioned above.  Please ensure you add 
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None inside @Component decorator.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None})
```

If you are looking for Angular Material setup for .Net core 1.1 or 2.0 Angular SPA visual studio template. Please find the well documented setup instruction details [here](http://fiyazhasan.me/adding-angular-material-in-aspnet-core-spa-template/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how many may find this useful, but restarting ng server worked after trying different solutions from Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me adding in css section of index.html

```
 <link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

As mentioned here [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Answer (score 0):

Check any other @imports in your css or scss file. I experienced this issue and could not resolve it until other imports had been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Add *@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"*; to style.css of your angular project .

In case you want any other theme just folow the steps:
**Node modules -> @angular -> material -> prebuilt-themes ->**

i)**deeppurple-amber** : *@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css*

ii)**indigo-pink** : *@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css*

iii)**pink-bluegrey** : *@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css*

iv)**purple-green** : *@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css*

*And if you want to read you can visit* :[Theming your Angular Material app](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you and I found the solution in one of the comments. Since that solution worked for me, I want to post it as an answer.

If your project was already running and you installed your material components afterwards, you need to restart your project first. That alone can be the fix already.

Answer (score 0):

Material design modules contains scss, migrate css files into scss from following two steps:

1. npm i schematics-scss-migrate
2. ng g schematics-scss-migrate:scss-migrate

Hope this works fro everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error once. What worked for me was to stop and restart ng serve. If you are serving your angular app when adding material or making changes in angular.json, you must restart ng serve for changes to take effect.