# How can I use the MdPaginator style found in the official example? (Material v2.0.0-beta.8)

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to insert in my project an Angular Material table which uses pagination. I have managed to make it run by looking at the example, but when I try to select the number of `Items per page`, instead of a nice [drop-down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrSt5.png), I get a weird `div` at the end of the page.
[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6Zbk.png)

I tried to add `import { MdSelectModule } from '@angular/material';` to my app but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was the lack of a `prebuilt-theme` imported in the `styles.css` file, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme).