# Use Angular material in MEAN-stack app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have been checking out Angular material in my Angular CLI project and find it to be extremely useful.

Now, I have another MEAN stack project where I would like to use Angular Material. One of the steps needed to use Material is adding a theme to the styles.css file. I did it like this:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Someone pointed out that import won't be recognized in my type of structure (something with webpack, see below). I also got the following error:

> Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components
>   may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide:
>   https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Because of the difference of the structure between my mean stack app and an Angular CLI this doesn't find the theme and thus doesn't work.

Could someone please explain me how to fix this. It would be really handy to be able to use Material in that mean stack app.

**a screenshot of the structure of my MEAN stack app**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular material Could not find Angular Material core theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme)

Comment: This is not the same! The example you gave is an example of a CLI. I tried this and it doesn't work.