# importing theme's css not resolving material error

Tags: angular-material

I am getting the following error in my Angular 6 app

`Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming`

I have imported the following theme in my `app.component.css` but I am still getting this error on browser's console

```
@import url("../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular material Could not find Angular Material core theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following statement about using pre-built themes in the [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme):

> If you're using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your `styles.css` file

You should have the import statement in your application's main stylesheet -  `styles.css` - not in `app.component.css`. Also, note another statement in the guide:

> The actual path will depend on your server setup.