# Angular Material Tree isn't displayed correctly using angular example

Tags: css, angular, tree, angular-material

after successfully installing `@angular/material`, `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/animations` using `npm install --save`, I tried to rebuild the example of a flat tree given by angular [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qynnnvyrvrb?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.html).

After fixing the error message `Could not find Angular Material core theme` using this stack post solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme) with adding

`@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

to my global `styles.scss`, it still doesn't display the tree correctly.

[image]

There is no error given in console. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Angular Material Icon Font, otherwise the icons won't be displayed properly. Add this line in your `index.html` file:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

> For more information check the official [Getting
>   started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-6-optional-add-material-icons)
>   section of the Angular Material documentation.