# Angular Material theming or appearance issues

Tags: angular, angular-material

When import angular material controls it look like this.
[browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvFcK.png)

and material controls
[component.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j2sS.png)

where I chose theme during angular material installation.
[angular.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp9xG.png)

Though its correct syntactically but I do not know what problem behind this. How to display angular material controls look like as shown in angular material site?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer. It is the theming issue in Angular. You need to fix this issue by the following steps.

import below URL to 'style.css' file in 'src' folder.

@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

or in 'angular.json' file add the above URL to the "style" property. See the below link.

#### Results

Before importing URL into style.css or style property of angular.json:

[image: Before importing URL into style.css or style property of angular.json]

After importing URL into style.css or style property of angular.json:

[image: After importing URL into style.css or style property of angular.json]

**References:**

- [Angular Material guide website](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme)
- [Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme)

Comment: This happens only if you forgot to add angular material to your project with 
ng add @angular/material. I mean there is option for prebuilt-themes.