# cant import Angular material v15 prebuild legacy theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I updated Angular and Material to v15, and I want to use legacy components, but when I try to import legacy prebuild theme I get this error.

[image: IMPORT]
[image: ERROR]

If I import the material prebuilt-themes(not legacy ones) the compiler builds successfully, but I need to use legacy components and I need legacy prebuild theme

[image: modules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to import it with `../node_modules/@angular`

Quite the same like:
[Angular material Could not find Angular Material core theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230852/angular-material-could-not-find-angular-material-core-theme)