# Is using ~ to import CSS with Angular from node_modules part of Angular's usage contract?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Some Angular demos import CSS using the `~` character like this:

```
 import `~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes`?
```

[IIUC webpack supports supports `~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535760/what-does-a-tilde-in-a-css-url-do) as a means to resolve CSS packages from the `node_modules` directory.  Can the `~` character be used in place of `node_modules` in general when importing css with Angular?  In other words is this a part of Angular usage contract for how CSS should be imported or are we just getting this feature as a "side effect" enabled by webpack?

If not does Angular have another approach that it recommends when importing NPM CSS packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the Webpack loader feature, documented here ex. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#usage and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1789

In general, to import CSS, it does recognize relative path, ex. `@import "../abc.css"`. But the best way is using `~`, as long as your css is stored inside `node_modules`.