# Import CSS from "node_modules" in Webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

Some third-party modules I'm using have their own CSS files. I'd like to include them in my app's one, single CSS file, which is processed by Webpack. How can CSS files under "node_modules" be imported into my CSS file?

For example, I'm using the third-party `react-select` module, but I can't import its CSS file from `node_modules`:

```
@import 'react-select/dist/react-datetime.css';
```

The relevant loader in `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            url: false
          }
        }
      ]
    })
  }
```

Comment: I,m interested in using @import the same way, but with Vite (not webpack)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You can import files relative to your project's root (resolving `node_modules/` from the root folder) by prefixing with a tilde `~`:

```
@import '~react-select/dist/react-datetime.css';
```

This is a poorly documented Webpack (a redundant phrase) convention, see https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/12#issuecomment-41940311 and [What does a `~` tilde in a CSS `url()` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535760/what-does-a-tilde-in-a-css-url-do)

Comment: Note that it is now documented:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#import
"To import assets from a node_modules path (include resolve.modules) and for alias, prefix it with a ~"
Also, note that it is not a core webpack feature but a feature of css-loader.

Comment: I had to remove the .css extension for it to work for some reason

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue today. After all, all I had to do was to [configure `resolve`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/) in my webpack config file. I hope this will help somebody.

Webpack version I used:

```
"webpack": "^4.37.0",
```

In a webpack config file, the following should be configured:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.json', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: ['node_modules'],
  },
```

or

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'some-library': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/some-library'),
    }
  },
```

In a css file, we can access a library by a relative path from `node_modules`:

```
@import '~some-library/src/some-css-file';
```

Comment: This worked for me, but the @import statement needed to be `@import 'node_modules/lib-name/file-name';`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using too many things from one node_modules folder you can also create an alias by passing this following option

```
options: {
    url: false,
    includePaths: [
        // this one for using node_modules as a base folder
        path.resolve('node_modules'),
        // this one for using sass as the base folder
        path.resolve('node_modules/flag-icon-css/sass')
    ]
}
```

After the configuration, you can import as you were trying in your question.

Comment: this is not recommended because `node_modules` usually too much big, this makes the searching process too much slow, at least make it the latest search path\

Answer (score 0):

I use Webpack 5. I also have been having a problem of not being able to import an external .css file from an external library. I tried adding `resolve:[...]` property to my `webpack.config.js` file, among other tryings, but all that was to no avail: webpack did not inject styles. Then I discovered a following hack: instead of importing .css in the usual `import "external-lib/style.css"` manner (which didn't help me in my case), I did a named import as follows:

```
import necessaryStyle from "external-lib/style.css";
const ReactComponent = () => {
    console.log("necessity logging: ", necessaryStyle);
...}
```

The console.log statement will print `undefined` but the trick worked in my case. The external styles were injected into the `<style><style/>` tags of my .html document.

Answer (score 0):

simply, prefix `~` to be replaced with the path of node_modules at compile time.

```
@import '~package-name/css-file';
```

however, **this is a webpack feature** (not an Angular feature).

since Angular projects now use esbuild, this feature will no longer work in newer Angular versions

**for EsBuild use:**

```
@import 'package-name/css-file.css';
```