# Css not working for intro.js module in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intro.js

I have added Intro.js as below in one of my components:

```
import introJs from 'intro.js';
```

Then called it in componentDidMount

```
    componentDidMount() {
    introJs().start();
}
```

Element where I am using it at:

```
 <div className={cx('dropDownSortingBlock')}>
                {!isTrending && <div className={cx('dropDown')} data-intro={'Hello step one!'}>
```

However when i import css into a parent component

[image]

It doesn't render the component.

[image]

Update:

I tried using intro.js react wrapper and i have imported css directly into my file now.

However it just doesn't work

```
 constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            showMessage: false,
            type: '',
            message: '',
            stepsEnabled: true,
            initialStep: 0,
            steps: [
                {
                    element: '.snapshotWrapper',
                    intro: 'Hello step',
                },
                {
                    element: '.snapshotWrapperNew',
                    intro: 'Hello Sort wrapper',
                },
            ],
        };
    }
```

**In render**

```
  <Steps
            enabled={this.state.stepsEnabled}
            steps={this.state.steps}
            initialStep={this.state.initialStep}
            onExit={this.onExit}
                    />
```

Below is what shows up:

[image]

Comment: By `doesn't render` you mean the component is not present in DOM at all, or you simply can't see it?

Comment: The component is present @AdamKosmala the css isn't getting applied

Comment: I would verify if `ListLandingPage.css` is loaded at all anywhere and if the imported files are available in your css bundle. I'm not familiar with introJs, but maybe try also replacing your import with `import * as introJs from 'intro.js'`

Comment: @vini Please raise this on their github

Comment: @vini I'm presuming you're using webpack? If so what's your config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're importing the `css` file from the package in `node_modules` , Add the `~` to your import in `ListLandingPage.css` :

```
@import "~intro.js/introjs.css";
```

see [Import CSS from "node_modules" in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49518277/import-css-from-node-modules-in-webpack)

Or, import it in your component ( without the `~` ) :

```
import introJs from 'intro.js';
import 'intro.js/introjs.css';
```

Howerver, I would suggest you use the [React wrapper around Intro.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js-react) for a React app.

they even have a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/o2A4gwXE3?hidenavigation=1) to get started

Comment: I tried the React Wrapper It didnt work out same issue will try this thanks.

Comment: am getting module loader failed

Comment: when using the `~` or when importing it in the component (without the `~`)?

Answer (score 1):

Please use react wrapper for intro.js.

1. npm install intro.js-react
2. also install intro js -- > npm install intro.js --save
3. then you can import css files from node modules like this below
   import "intro.js/introjs.css"
   themes are also available on the themes folder.(for eg: import "intro.js/themes/introjs-
   nassim.css";)
4. Wrapper works similarly. Define steps / hints inside component. for that :-
   import { Steps, Hints } from "intro.js-react";

Answer (score 0):

Did you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js-react . It is a small React wrapper around Intro.js. The wrapper provides support for both steps and hints