# webpack.config with font-awesome

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome-5

I am going to use fontawesome 5 in my source code, but I have some trouble here.

I've installed 4 npm modules.

> "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
>
> "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.25",
>
> "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.11.2",
>
> "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",

webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Webpack Config
 */
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
// const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

// plugins
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

// the path(s) that should be cleaned
let pathsToClean = [
    'dist',
    'build'
]

// the clean options to use
let cleanOptions = {
    root: __dirname,
    verbose: false, // Write logs to console.
    dry: false
}

module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "react-hot-loader/patch", "./src/index.js"],
    output: {
        // The build folder.
        path: resolveApp('build'),
        // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
        // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
        // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
        filename: 'assets/js/[name].[hash:8].js',
        chunkFilename: 'assets/js/[name].[hash:8].chunk.js',
        // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
        publicPath: publicPath,
        hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
        hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src/index.js',
        compress: true,
        port: 3000, // port number
        historyApiFallback: true,
        quiet: true
    },
    // resolve alias (Absolute paths)
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
            Containers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers/'),
            Assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/'),
            Util: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/util/'),
            Routes: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/routes/'),
            Constants: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/constants/'),
            Redux: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/redux/'),
            Data: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/data/')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            // Scss compiler
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: false,
                    ecma: 6,
                    mangle: true
                },
                sourceMap: true
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
        ]
    },
    performance: {
        hints: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "warning" : false
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'src/assets/img', to: 'assets/img' }, { from: 'src/assets/fonts', to: 'assets/fonts' }
        ]),
        new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
            favicon: './public/favicon.ico'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "assets/css/[name].[hash:8].css"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[hash:8].css",
            chunkFilename: "[id].[hash:8].css"
        })
    ]
};
```

And I've got below error when I wrote `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css';`

```
Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                        3:21:04 AM
 error  in ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
    at handleParseError (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:469:19)
    at doBuild.err (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5)
    at runLoaders (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12)
    at E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)    at provider (E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9)
    at E:\workspace\pulse\projectai-pulse-survey\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

 @ ./src/components/MyMap/KGraph/index.js 17:0-54
 @ ./src/components/MyMap/index.js
 @ ./src/routes/mymap/index.js
 @ ./src/routes/index.js
 @ ./src/containers/App.js
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index.js
```

I've tried to many ways to solve this, but all are failed.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I've added the below codes to webpack.config.js

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        { 
            test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case in *file-loader* or *url-loader* instead of testing for only image file extentions, I've also added font extentions like this:

```
module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {//your options},
      }
      // ...other loaders here
    ],
  },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the import of the ‘CSS’ file to import ’'~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid.css'’, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49523565/6094030).