# Angular - how to configure scss files so that you don't need to include the full path?

Tags: angular, sass, nativescript

I'm building an app with NativeScript 6.4.1 and Angular 8.

I need to import my sass variables into all of my component scss files.

component.scss

```
@import '../../../css/variables';

.sidedrawer-header {
    background-color: $vivid_cerulean;
    padding: 50px;
}

.sidedrawer-content {
    background-color: $vivid_cerulean2;
}
```

_variables.scss

```
$navy_blue: #105195;
$vivid_cerulean: #28abe2;
$white: #ffffff;
$dark_navy_blue: #063260;
$light_grey: #eeeeee;
$error_red: #eb2026;
$vivid_cerulean2: #3eb4e5;
```

I see that the import statements could be cumbersome in the future with all the different paths.

Is there a way to make the import statement cleaner?

I would like it to be something like this:

```
@import '~variables'
```

My project has a webpack.config.js file, and an agular.json file.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the documentation [Additional build and test options](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#additional-build-and-test-options) for the [stylePreprocessorOptions](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-preprocessor-options).

From Angular documentation:

To add paths, use the stylePreprocessorOptions option:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "cli": {
    "packageManager": "npm"
  },
  "projects": {
    "your-project": {
      "root": "projects/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "assets": [],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": []
            },
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

Files in that folder, such as src/style-paths/_variables.scss, can be imported from anywhere in your project without the need for a relative path:

```
// src/app/app.component.scss
// A relative path works
@import '../style-paths/variables';
// But now this works as well
@import 'variables';
```

And bty the way the tilde (~) is use for node_modules path [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535760/what-does-a-tilde-in-a-css-url-do?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Where in the config file do you put those settings? I got an error.

Comment: In architect -> build -> options (angular.json)

Comment: property architect is not allowed

Comment: This did not work for me there is an error:   "architect": {
      "build": {
        "options": {
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": [
                  "src/css"
                ]
              }
        }
      }
  } I am using node-sass

Comment: My bad, I specified, it is in "angular.json" not in "webpack.config.js"

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm getting the error as well in angular.json

Comment: I have updated my post, check above. I hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help. It still didn't work for me. Is a webpack setting also required?         
                {
                    test: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "nativescript-dev-webpack/style-hot-loader",
                        { loader: "css-loader", options: { url: false } },
                        "sass-loader"
                    ]
                },
                { test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /[\/|\\]app\.scss$/, use: ["raw-loader", "resolve-url-loader", "sass-loader"] },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211740/discussion-between-lievno-and-user1261710).