# Style import (with webpack) on react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a React project and I'm trying to use this library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery)

from npm And from the Documentation, they say we must add these instructions to import the CSS

my component

```
import React from 'react'
import "~react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
import "~react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss";
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
 export  function Features() {


const images = [
    {
      original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/',
      thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/',
    },
    {
      original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/',
      thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/',
    },
    {
      original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/',
      thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/',
    },
  ];
return (
  
     
    <div>
      <ImageGallery items={images} />;
  
    </div>
   )
 }
```

my packeg json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.2.7",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^3.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
},
```

But when I add this in my Component it gives me this ERROR

If there is no solution, please suggest to me the name of a library similar to this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone, the issue is resolved
I added this to the component

import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";

```
  import React from 'react'
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import {ImgGallery} from "./Styled.js"
export  function ShopDetails() {


    const images = [
        {
          original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1000/600/',
          thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1018/250/150/',
        },
        {
          original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1000/600/',
          thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1015/250/150/',
        },
        {
          original: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1000/600/',
          thumbnail: 'https://picsum.photos/id/1019/250/150/',
           },
         ];
         return (
      
         
          <ImgGallery>
          <ImageGallery thumbnailPosition="left" useBrowserFullscreen={false} 
          showPlayButton={false} autoPlay={true} items={images} />;
      
        </ImgGallery>
        )
          }
```

Comment: so you have fixed your imports, "~" in path makes special sense to css-loader but not to JS imports. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535760/what-does-a-tilde-in-a-css-url-do

Answer (score 0):

You must import only the components from the library, not the css or scss files.
For example `import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery'` and use it below like `<ImageGallery/>` as usual.

If it's not successful than try to import css/scss files to `index.js`

Comment: I tried both cases if I do not call the style file the slider does not work

Comment: Do you know the name of any library similar to it?

Comment: There is a library called `Swiper` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swiper)
It has various style carousel sliders.

Comment: I know about it, but I cannot control the vertical box. Or rather, it does not have a similar shape as I would like