# Vue Cli Webpack background url path issue

Tags: sass, webpack, vue.js

Using vue cli.

For some reason, SOME of my images, if I refer to them directly in the scss and don't bind them dynamically to my vue object have issues with relative paths.

Say I have a vue template with a div called box.
Box has a background url of this:

.box{
background: url('../img/box.jpg')

That works locally just fine when I run npm run dev.
But when I run build, it doesn't work. 404 error.
I have also tried doing this:

```
.box{
background: url('~../img/box.jpg')
```

And that didn't work.

So there's this:

[webpack css-loader not finding images within url() reference in an external stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549268/webpack-css-loader-not-finding-images-within-url-reference-in-an-external-styl)

And when I change this in webpack.config:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
```

To:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
```

It'll create Chunk Images in my webpack build with hashes for cacheing. And just for those specific images that aren't bound in the vue object.

And then I have to drag those images over to the root dist folder....rather than what I want to do which is keep them in an img folder relative to the html file ( html file is simply ):

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vue</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>


    <app></app>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Question is, do I have to bind every single vue img from the data...or can't I just directly refer to a image if I know it's not going to be changed.

Or is there some setting in my sass loader/webpack that i'm missing.

Here's my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: './dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  },
  vue: {
    html: {
      root: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'vue-html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin()
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the url prefix of '~@/'

```
background-image: url('~@/assets/box.jpg');
```

Comment: Solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to replicate your problem with the following steps:

Assuming the following directory:

```
root/
  dist/
  src/
    assets/
      |--box.jpg
    components/
      |--home.vue
```

And home.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="foo">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  }
</script> 

<style>
  .foo {
    background: url('../assets/box.jpg')
  }
</style>
```

After building the application and save the files in the `dist` folder, everything works if I serve the built files using this command inside `dist` folder (I use [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) for simplicity):

```
lite-server index.html
```

However, if I go back to the root folder and try to do the same:

```
lite-server dist/index.html
```

I will encounter the same problem as you.

How I usually get around this is by importing the image first and then using it with inline style:

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:style= "{ 'background-image': 'url(' + box + ')' }">
    Placeholder
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // @ is an alias to /src
  import box from '@/assets/box.jpg';

  export default {
    data() {
      return { box };
    }
  }
</script>
```

Also check out the following discussions:

- [Github: background image best practice](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/646)
- [Github: html image src require not respecting webpack aliases?](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/193)
- [Github: vue-loader not processing images in dynamic component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/814)
- [Github: problem with background url](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/256)
- [StackOverflow: Vue.js data-bind style backgroundImage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242272/vue-js-data-bind-style-backgroundimage-not-working)
- [StackOverflow: webpack css-loader not finding images within url() reference in an external stylesheet](http://webpack%20css-loader%20not%20finding%20images%20within%20url()%20reference%20in%20an%20external%20stylesheet)

Answer (score 2):

depends on where your root set, you could try `background: url('~/assets/img/box.jpg')` or `background: url('~/src/assets/img/box.jpg')`,
one of them should work