# vue-cli: I can use @ in <template> but not in <style>

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

In vue-cli, because it's defined in `webpack.base.conf.js`, I can use `@` like this in `<template>`:

```
<img src="@/assets/logo.png">
```

but not like this in `<style>`:

```
background: url(@/assets/logo.png);
```

actually I can write it as `url(../assets/logo.png)` and it works, but it makes the `url` depend on the component's path: I would have to rewrite the `url` if I move the components (to subdirectory, for example).

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Others seem to have the same issue.  Have you seen this discussion?  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/pull/135#150

Answer (score 0):

If you use

`url(../assets/logo.png)`

there's a chance if may not work for deployment due to relative path problems.

The safest way is use inline styles instead:

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:style= "{ 'background-image': 'url(' + box + ')' }">
    Placeholder
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // @ is an alias to /src
  import box from '@/assets/box.jpg';

  export default {
    data() {
      return { box };
    }
  }
</script>
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648785/vue-cli-webpack-background-url-path-issue/48687942#48687942) for more details.