# 404s on some images from Webpack url-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, urlloader

There are a *lot* of questions on this, and a lot of answers, read below to see what I've tried, and how they didn't work. I assume my problem is coming from a fundamental misunderstanding of how url-loader works.

I have images included like this in my .less files. I am using two different formats as an example of what I've tried.

**app.less**

```
#logo {
  background-image: url("~/img/LoginMarketingImage.png");
}
#logotwo{
  background-image: url("../public/img/LoginMarketingImage2.png");
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
    entry: {
        app: './public/js/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
```

I have also tried

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
    entry: {
        app: './public/js/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
```

As well as below, based on: [webpack css-loader not finding images within url() reference in an external stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549268/webpack-css-loader-not-finding-images-within-url-reference-in-an-external-styl)

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
    entry: {
        app: './public/js/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'https://localhost:9081/'
    },
```

My module config looks like

**webpack.config.js**

```
   module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
                limit: 2000000,
                name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[ext]')
            }
        },
     ]
   }
```

I have experimented with a limit of 1 and a higher limit, to see if inline vs non-inlined works.

My folder structure is as follows

```
  build/
  less/
     app.less
  public/
     img/
        LoginMarketingImage.png
        LoginMarketingImage2.png

  config/
     webpack/
        webpack.config.js
```

**My Results**

If I set the limit to 1, and force all images to be output directly, the only time they are output is if they use the `url("../")` syntax. `url("~/")` throw no webpack errors, but the images don't get output to the build folder. In this case, the images using `url("../")` syntax throw no errors in the browser either. However, this is not ideal, as I want to take advantage of url-loader's ability to return a DataURL. In this scenario, images using `url("~/")` syntax give the error `GET https://localhost:9081/img/logo.png 404 (Not Found)`, regardless of `publicPath` setting.

If I set the limit to 20000000, obviously no images are put in the build folder by `file-loader`. However, all images return a 404 in the browser, regardless of `publicPath` setting.

I feel like I'm misunderstanding how to use `url-loader`. **What kind of configuration do I need, and how should I be requiring my files inside less, to take advantage of url-loader's ability to return DataURLs?**

EDIT: Based on [this issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader/issues/19#issuecomment-196814094), I have ensured that css sourcemaps are disabled.

Comment: Would be v helpful if you could include a repo with the full failing test case - for example the css and less loaders aren't included here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't pinpoint the problem here, but it seems like the publicPath config is the problem. I [threw together a sample gist](https://gist.github.com/guilhermehn/951fc92d976f515a1f5555abb252d508) with the minimium you need to get the url-loader working properly.

Some things to note:

- Make sure the `test` option is correct
- You didn't mentioned which version of webpack you're using, but I assume it's > 2. If it's == 2 then you should upgrade because the newer versions fixed a lot of bugs and the config API is almost 100% compatible
- Do not use the tilde import path, it's a shortcut to `project-root-dir/node_modules` (at least in webpack 1.x)
- I assume you're using webpack-dev-server. If not, then you should not need to set the publicPath and such
- Do not change url-loader's `name` option unless you got everything working without it. Changing it's path can confuse webpack